# How to up my div inner overflow-x:auto;?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to show my `div` `inner overflow scroll`? i need show this `div`. I did position absolute and `z index` but not showing `div`. it is showing inner parent `div`. Someone help me? Thanks a lot :)

```
    <div class="otobus_alan">
  <div class="otobus">
    <a href="" class="koltuk">Koltuk
    <div class="ekstra_div">
        Test
    </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>

    .otobus_alan {
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:100px;
  z-index:1;
}
.otobus {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width:1000px;
  height:180px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;

}

.ekstra_div {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  z-index:2;
  padding:25px;
  background:blue;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  top:-40px;
  left:100px;
}

.koltuk {
  float:left;
  background:white;
}
.koltuk:hover .ekstra_div {
    display:block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/musti_nation/pen/RyZBoe

Comment: alan will never overflow as octobus has a height of 180px (less than alan) - remove the height from `.octobus` and it may work as you want

Comment: i need height attribute.  :)

Comment: Then put the overflow on that

Comment: can you do on codepen?

Comment: errrrr `.otobus { overflow-x:auto }`

Comment: friend thank your for your help but, this area required overflow!

Comment: remove `display:none;` from `.ekstra_div`